# How to save a bitmap on storage in Android Q and later?

Tags: java, android, image, mediastore

In my application, I have to store a bitmap as a PNG file in shared memory, to make it visible for Gallery app. First, I tried to store the image in `/Android/data/package.name/files/Pictures`. I got this path from `context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)`. Images stored in this directory are not detected by Gallery. Then I read a few articles and SO posts about MediaStore and I tried to save my image with it.

This is a function that I use to store bitmap. It does not throw any exception, returns true, `bitmap.compress()` also returns true but I can't find any PNG image in device's memory. I tried to look for it using Gallery and file manager. I also tried to change it to save JPEG instead of PNG but it also does not work.

Could you help me to figure out why this function does not save image to device's store?

I tested it on Samsung A52s 5G, Android 12, OneUI 4.0.

```
private boolean saveImageToStorageAndroidQ(Bitmap bitmap, String filename) {
    filename = filename + ".png";
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, filename);
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/png");
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);

    final ContentResolver resolver = getActivity().getContentResolver();
    final Uri contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    Uri uri = resolver.insert(contentUri, values);

    try {
        OutputStream imageOutStream = resolver.openOutputStream(uri);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 95, imageOutStream);
        imageOutStream.flush();
        imageOutStream.close();
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    } finally {
        if (uri != null)
            resolver.delete(uri, null, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should also use column .IS_PENDING twice. The second time with update() function.

Comment: watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yZdlp-K0wmE)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this method. Thought it's long, it's better as the [other one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71795121/17133283) has been deprecated. Use this code:

```java
String filename = "name.png";
File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File dest = new File(sd, filename);

try {
     FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dest);
     bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
     out.flush();
     out.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Supposed that you have the image taken in bitmap format, this one is ok for Android older versions (tried on Android 7.0 Nougat Xiaomi)  :

```
    String new_Date = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "-"
                            + ((c.get(Calendar.MONTH)) + 1) + "-"
                            + c.get(Calendar.YEAR) + " " + c.get(Calendar.HOUR)
                            + "-" + c.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + "-"
                            + c.get(Calendar.SECOND);    



MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(),bitmap,new_Date,"image:"+new_Date);
```

Now, for Android version Q and later this method is suggested:

```
private void saveBitmapImage(Bitmap bitmap, @NonNull String name) throws IOException {
    boolean savedSuccessfully;
    OutputStream fos;

 
     ContentResolver resolver = mContext.getContentResolver();
     ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
     contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, name);
     contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "image/png");
     contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, "DCIM/"+IMAGES_FOLDER_NAME);
     Uri imageUri = resolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues);
     fos = resolver.openOutputStream(imageUri);


     savedSuccessfully = bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
     fos.flush();
     fos.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a very easy method:

```java
MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), bitmap, filename, "Description");
```

This is deprecated. Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71798955/17133283) answer

Comment: According to documentation, this method is deprecated.

Comment: But, it still works

Comment: then try my another answer